# Asterisk for custom server side validator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a custom server side validator. It is used to validate multiple different controls, that are validated in comparison to each other. For instance, if one drowndownlist has value x, then the other drop down list must have some value selected.

The form is being created dynamically in a repeater function and bound on the code side.

How can I only use one custom validator and display asterisks next to the appropriate control that does not meet the required criteria.

Currently, I am simply displaying an error message in the summary, but I would like to give a little more information to the user as to which control in specific is incorrect.

One option I considered was putting a label control next to each control to be validated, setting its visibility to hidden initially, and then setting it to visible with a value of "*" if that control failed validation, but is there an easier way?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom validator for each row of data that needs validated. This is done dynamically, in the repeater control, and then the asterisk is shown on the row that needs something modified. This worked out well for what I was needing. Thanks!